# Why could wget not work with PHP's exec function?

Tags: php

My script tries to exec() wget but seems to fail (though, no error raises up). What could be the problem? Should I tune PHP somehow? I just installed Apache and PHP on Ubuntu...

Comment: What's the command line you pass to exec?

Comment: I've tried like this: exec('wget -O /var/www/videos/'.$_GET['one'].'/'.$file.' '.$one, $output); and also like this: exec('/usr/bin/wget -O /var/www/videos/'.$_GET['one'].'/'.$file.' '.$one, $output); but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Add [third parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to exec() to find out the [exit code of wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `wget` is not in the (search) path of the apache/php process.
Did you try an absolute path to the wget executable?

Answer (score 0):

What is your `$_GET['one']`? The name of a video file? A number? A url? What's `$file`? What' `$one`?

Obvious error sources:

1. Are all of those variables set? If $one is blank, then wget has nowhere to go to fetch your file. If $_GET['one'] and $file are blank, then your output file will most likely not exist, either because the directory can't be found ($_GET['one']) is empty, or $file is empty, causing wget to try and output to a directory name, which is not allowed.
2. 'illegal' characters in any of the variables. Does `$file` contain shell meta-characters? Any of ;?*/\ etc...? Those will all screw up the command line.
3. Why are you using wget anyways? You're passing raw query parameters out to a shell, which is just asking for trouble. It would be trivial to pass in shell metacharacters, which would allow remote users to run ANYTHING on your webserver. Consider the following query:

   http://example.com/fetch.php?one=;%20rm%20-rf%20/%20;

which in your script becomes:

```
wget -O /var/www/videos/; rm -rf / ;/$file $one
```

and now your script is happily deleting everything on the server which your web server's user has permissions for.