# imagemagick doesn't work

Tags: php, imagemagick

I can't make imagemagick work..

## edit

CHMOD is set to `777`

I found the error log.. no error concerning imagemagick is reported.. I just made up an error to check if it was the correct error.log - and it was...

```
[Thu Nov 03 14:47:49 2011] [error] [client 94.145.177.221] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant sd - assumed 'sd' in /var/www/_im.php on line 24
```

Here is the code

```
$base = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/';
$src = $base.'invoice.pdf';
$dst = $base.'invoice.png';

$syntax = '/usr/local/bin/convert -debug coders -log "%u %m:%l %e" '.$src.' '.$dst;

echo $syntax;

exec($syntax);
```

`is_file($src)` returns true

Comment: What does the script output?  What shows up in your server logs?

Comment: I don't know where to find the log?

Comment: Why doesnt it work? What do you expect, what does it do instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [exec() command not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578780/exec-command-not-working) or [Why could wget not work with PHP's exec function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528871/why-could-wget-not-work-with-phps-exec-function) and so many more.

Comment: @clarkk, add these: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); at top of your code.

Comment: @tjheuvel > no file is returned

Comment: @clarkk, without errors/warnings it like trying catch wind in plain fields.. But my guess your programs fails because file permissions (it just guess).

Comment: question edited.. found the error log, but no errors concerning imagemagick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unable to locate your webservers/vhosts [`error.log`](http://www.google.com/search?q=apache+error.log+/var/log) this can oftentimes help to figure out some problems:

```
 print `sh -c "/usr/local/bin/convert -help" 2>&1`;
```

(Except it's blockend via safe_mode and open_basedir as well. But you would have found out with a PHP warning, unless you had turned them off.)

Answer (score 0):

You should call `convert` with `-debug coder` (instead of coder-**s**).